# Getting Depedenccy Property Error in XAML only

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am adding an extended property to an existing user control, it works fine at design time and runtime with no errors. I do however get an error showing in design mode in the XAML which is:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SfdName' property of type 'ExtendedSfMaskedEdit'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

How do I clear this please?

XAML below:

```
<local:ExtendedSfMaskedEdit SfdName="{Binding TestTag}" />
```

Code below:

```
Public SfdNameProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SfdName", GetType(String), GetType(ExtendedSfMaskedEdit), New UIPropertyMetadata("", AddressOf SfdNameChanged))

Private Sub SfdNameChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)

End Sub

<Bindable(True)>
Public Property SfdName As String
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(SfdNameProperty), String)
    End Get
    Set
        SetValue(SfdNameProperty, Value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: See the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties). The DependencyProperty field and the PropertyChangedCallback method must be Shared.

Comment: Thanks, I should have spotted that